# Is there a way to find and extract tables using OCR in python/Azure?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on writing an azure custom skill to find and extract tables from large documents. Specifically, i'm trying to find something that will pull out dungeons and dragons PDF documents, which can then be used as a custom skill by azure cognitive search.

So far, i've tried writing a custom skill which searches for something that should only be present in a stat block, the challenge rating. This works in the local test environment, but fails when applied as an azure custom skill, with a message to the effect of "data does not contain text" even when it is paired with an OCR skill to extract and transform the data to text. All the documents are PDF.

Is there a way to remove this validation without breaking the skill? Or is there a better way of writing this skill? Currently it's just pulling out instances of the challenge rating, which isn't quite perfect but is close enough.

````
import azure.functions as func
import json
import re
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        body = json.dumps(req.get_json())
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Invalid body",
             status_code=400
        )
    if body:
        result = compose_response(body, identify_stat_blocks)
        return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Invalid body",
             status_code=400
        )
def identify_stat_blocks(text):
    if type(text) is not str:
        raise TypeError('Input data is not text/str')
    challenge = get_all_matches(text, ['(?i)Challenge[\s]+[0-9\s]+'])
    extracteds = {"Challenge Rating":challenge}
    return extracteds
def get_all_matches(text, reference_re):
    retlist = []
    for i in reference_re:
        matches = re.findall(i, text)
        if matches:
            retlist.extend(matches)
    if len(retlist) > 0:
        return retlist
    else:
        return None
def compose_response(json_data, func):
    values = json.loads(json_data)['values']
    # Prepare the Output before the loop
    results = {}
    results["values"] = []
    for value in values:
        output_record = transform_value(value, func)
        if output_record != None:
            results["values"].append(output_record)
    return json.dumps(results, ensure_ascii=False)
# Perform an operation on a record
def transform_value(value, func):
    try:
        recordId = value['recordId']
    except AssertionError  as error:
        return None
 # Validate the inputs
    try:         
        assert ('data' in value), "'data' field is required."
        data = value['data']        
        assert ('text' in data), "'text' field is required in 'data' object."      
    except AssertionError  as error:
        return (
            {
            "recordId": recordId,
            "errors": [ { "message": "Error:" + error.args[0] }   ]       
            })
    challenge = func(data['text'])
    return ({
            "recordId": recordId,
            "data": {
                "text": challenge
                    }
            })```

I'd be super grateful for any help/guidance!
````

Comment: have you considered using Forms Recognizer Power Skill? 

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/tree/main/Vision/FormRecognizer

Comment: @Farzzy-MSFT I did look into it, but the document sizes are too large for it

Comment: Perhaps try splitting the documents into smaller chunks?

Comment: Even taking it down to a single page seems to be too OCR intense for it, by which point it would be as quick to just find the tables and screenshot them manually. But thank you :)